# Reference parent method call from drived DLL

Tags: .net, inheritance, dll

I have a DLL Core.dll, and then a DLL DataLayer.dll.

Core.dll has reference of DataLayer.dll

In Datalayer.dll, I need to access some information which resides in Core.dll. Is there a way that I can call a method residing inside core.dll?

Basically, In datalayer, I need to call some shared properties in Core.dll which have some information like Current logged in user id and maybe some other.

Not sure if that is possible, if that is, Please let me know.

```
thanks
```

Sameers

Comment: Why doesn't the caller pass in that information? You can't make the two assemblies refer to each other.

Comment: I agree with Jon. You may also move shared data to another DLL and DataLayer.dll uses that.

Comment: You are right that I can create a third DLL which can be referenced by both dlls. but when you have a very big project already developed, its not that easy to make such big changes. I can't pass over information as parameter as well as there are literally hundred of thousands location where the datalayer methods are being called and can't change them all. I know we may do a workaround, but having something simple not affecting any existing code is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, cause C# compiler want to know the order of compiling assemblies. Any dependent assembly should be compiled *after* an assembly that it depends.

So you need to break the physical dependency. F.e. you can place a set of cyclic-referenced classes in separate assembly.

Or you can hide a current user inside the "build-in" .NET interface `IPrincipal`, then both of you assemblies will depend on a .NET core that is no considered a bad practice.

Ideally, you should also remove logical dependencies. See f.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle.